# how do I resolve this types conflict?

Tags: jquery, node.js, typescript, npm

I'm executing grunt task "typescriptUsingTsConfig" and I'm getting the following error:

```
Conflicting definitions for 'jquery' found at:

 'C:/CODE/Platts.Bentek.Web.Benport/src/Platts.Bentek.Web.Benport.Website/
node_modules/ng2-select2/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts' 

---and---

 'C:/CODE/Platts.Bentek.Web.Benport/src/Platts.Bentek.Web.Benport.Website/
node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts'. 

Consider installing a specific version of this library to resolve the conflict.
```

What is a good strategy for resolving this conflict? My main app is greenfield development so it can use the latest version of jQuery. However, by drilling into the node_modules for ng2-select2, it looks like it's wired up to use jQuery v2.0.39. Is there a way to use both versions of jQuery?  Or is the main app limited by the lowest version of jQuery used by a child component?

**UPDATE**

I was assuming that a jquery @types configuration existed at the app root level and also as a nested implementation within the select2 control b/c the error message stated that there were conflicting definitions b/t these 2 locations. So I tried simply deleting the jquery @types directory from the app root directory but now the ts grunt task returns the following error:

```
"Warning: node_modules/@types/select2/index.d.ts(8,1): error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'jquery'. Use --force to continue."
```

So a reference exists in select2/index.d.ts which points to a jquery @types directory. But when the jquery @types directory exists, the ts grunt task errors out with a version mismatch.  Any idea how this configuration may have gotten to this point or how to fix?

Comment: Is your jQuery version conflict issue in node.js code or in client-side code?  If it's in node.js code, what are you doing with jQuery on the server?  There are ways to use more than one version of jQuery on the client, but your first 10 choices should be to find a way to avoid that so everybody can use the same version.  Since you've shown us none of the specifics of who's trying to use jQuery for what, we can't really advise you on how to make them both use the same version.

Comment: the error is returned from typescriptUsingTsConfig grunt task as it tries to build/compile all of the ts in the app.  my app has a node_modules\jquery directory as well as a \node_modules\ng2-select2\node_modules\@types subdirectory. looks like ng2-select2 uses an older version of jQuery (2.0.39), hence the conflict. is there any type of setting or configuration I can use to allow the child component with the earlier version of jQuery use its own jQuery types while allowing the parent app to use the more recent verson of jQuery types?

Comment: There's a Typescript part of this problem and there's a jQuery part of this problem.  You should first tackle the jQuery part of this problem as you simply can't have two versions of jQuery in the same client page without special work because each will try to define the `jQuery` global symbol to be their own.  So, even if you found a way past the TypeScript part of the issue, you still have to face the jQuery version conflict.

Comment: I would suggest trying to figure out if you can force your two pieces of code to use the same version of jQuery.  This can't be the first time anyone using these modules has run into this issue so find where other people have been talking about how to handle this for your particular libraries.  Then, if you figure that out, your TypeScript issue goes away when you get both libraries to use the same version of jQuery.

Comment: Also, you never answered whether this jQuery code is being used within node.js or in client-side Javascript (that may be served by your node.js server, but runs in the browser).  That may affect the solutions available.

Comment: Since ng2-select2 lets you pick which version of jQuery you want to install with it, have you simply tried using the same version of jQuery with it that you are using elsewhere?

Comment: jfriend00 - thanks for that tip!  I was not aware of that.  that seems to be the ideal solution.  i will try that

Comment: @jfriend00 - I added an "update" section to the bottom of my original post describing a weird problem scenario that I'm encountering with this :\